# Disable , Enable Kendo UI TreeView (checkbox) Jquery

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

i use kendo ui treeview (with checkbox) and i want to disable / enable nodes from jquery.

How Can I disable or enable Kendo UI TreeView (checkbox) With Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable:

```
$(".treeview .k-checkbox input").removeAttr("disabled");
$(".treeview .k-Icon").removeClass("k-minus-disabled");
$(".treeview .k-in").removeClass("k-state-disabled");
```

Disable:

```
$(".treeview .k-checkbox input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
$(".treeview .k-Icon").addClass("k-minus-disabled");
$(".treeview .k-in").addClass("k-state-disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var treeview = $("#tree").data("kendoTreeView");
var selectedNode = treeview.select();
//disabled node
treeview.enable(selectedNode, false);
```

the subject is old, but if it can help someone.